# Detecting faces from camera using Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I am currently trying to detect face from my laptop camera but for some reason the code I found is not giving a result. The code is starting the webcam and not giving any errors but no rectangles are drawn for the faces. No faces are being detected hence the for loop is never running, I tried changing the scale factor but that did not help. Both the xml files are in the same folder as the code. The code is as following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _,f=img.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(f,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = f[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',f)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
img.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello your program work fine, You have 2 small problems one you need Tab this code to put inside the while:

```
cv2.imshow('img',f)
if cv2.waitKey(25) == 27:
  break
```

And be sure the your xml files are founded this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _,f=img.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(f,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = f[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('Test',f)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
img.release()
```

Comment: I had tabbed the code just forgot to do it while posting here. Sorry for that. But my code is still not displaying any rectangles. Please help. Both xml files are in the same folder as the code.

Comment: I just run the code and works, maybe is your versión of OpenCV I have try it with OpenCV 3 on Mac and works nice

Comment: Thanks alot. There was an error in my xml files. The code worked.